# How to add axios and image upload url in this component ReactJS + DropZone?

Tags: reactjs, axios, dropzone

I have this component in React JS + Typescript and I need to make this Image uploading component functional.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";
import classNames from "classnames";
interface IUploadField {
    type: string;
    name: string,
    field: any;
    form: any;
    label?: string;
    subLabel?: string;
    errorMsg?: {};
    required?: boolean;
    placeholder?: string;
    elementClass?: string;
    formGrouoClass?: string;
    onFieldChange?: Function
}

function Upload(props: IUploadField) {
    const { field, form } = props
    const { setFieldValue } = form
    const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({
        accept: props.type + "",
        onDrop: (acceptedFiles: any) => {
            setFieldValue(field.name, acceptedFiles);
            // if (props.onFieldChange) {
            //     props.onFieldChange(acceptedFiles, props)
            // }
        }
    });

    return (
        <div className={classNames("form-group", props.formGrouoClass)} >
            <label htmlFor={props.label}>{props.label}
                <div className="sub-label">{props.subLabel}</div>
            </label>
            { }
            <div {...getRootProps({ className: "dropzone form-control mb-1" })}>
                <input {...getInputProps()} />
                {isDragActive ? (
                    <p>Drop the file here ...</p>
                ) : (
                    <p>Drag 'n' drop  file here, or click to select files

                    </p>
                )}
            </div>
            {props.type === 'image' && Array.isArray(field.value) && field.value?.map((f: any) => <img height="80" src={URL.createObjectURL(f)} />)}
            {props.type === 'video' && Array.isArray(field.value) && field.value?.map((f: any) => (
                <video height="80" controls>
                    <source src={URL.createObjectURL(f)} type="video/mp4"></source>
                    <source src={URL.createObjectURL(f)} type="video/ogg" ></source>
                </video>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Upload
```

I have no idea to how to add the axios in it so I can make the POST request to the url provided to me. Sorry I am new to the ReactJS